# Wrong type when mapping result rows using sea-query builder + sqlx

Tags: sea-query

I want to query a user from my `users` table of Postgres database.

```rs
...

// Build Query
let (sql, values) = Query::select()
    .columns([DbUser::Id, DbUser::Name, DbUser::Email])
    .from(DbUser::Table)
    .and_where(Expr::col(DbUser::Id).eq(user_id))
    .build(PostgresQueryBuilder);

// Execute query with sqlx
let result = bind_query(sqlx::query(&sql), &values)        
    .map(|row| {
      // I want to get access to my result values here
    })
    .fetch_optional(self.pool)
    .await?;
...
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't show the fields in the IntelliSense tooltip. See image below

[image]

But if I do the same request without `sea-query` using only `sqlx` it shows correct suggestion. See image below

[image]

I tried to follow [this example](https://github.com/SeaQL/sea-query/blob/eb5705e9ce7f7418c3f66f268f6ae65282cfcae4/examples/sqlx_postgres/src/main.rs#L137-L140) from the official documentation.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `use sqlx::Row;` to the top of the file and the issue disappeared.

I'm not sure what the "magic" behind this import is, but it works.

[image]